# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.PartialViewResultExecutor' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a `ToString()` method for Partial Views.

My usings :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

public static class ViewExtensions
{
    public static async Task<string> ToString(this PartialViewResult partialView, ActionContext actionContext)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var services = actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;
            var executor = services.GetRequiredService<PartialViewResultExecutor>();
            var view = executor.FindView(actionContext, partialView).View;
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(actionContext, view, partialView.ViewData, partialView.TempData, writer, new HtmlHelperOptions());
            await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET Core 2.2 I am getting this error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.PartialViewResultExecutor' has been registered.
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)

Comment: The line `services.GetRequiredService<PartialViewResultExecutor>()` is trying to get an instance of `PartialViewResultExecutor` from the DI container, but that type hasn't been registered. Has this code worked previously?

Comment: Yes , worked previously

Comment: So what can you suggest for this approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line in your `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class:

```
services.AddSingleton<PartialViewResultExecutor>();
```